# Component bindings in the Component definition instead of markup?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When defining a Vue.js Component, I've read you define bindings in the markup, like this:

```
<div id="app">

  <todo-item v-bind:item="todo" v-bind:key="todo.id" v-bind:class="[item.someValue]"></todo-item>

</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo'],
    template: '<div>{{ todo.text }}</div>'
  })
</script>
```

Is it possible to define your `v-bind`'s in your JavaScript definition of your Component instead of in the markup? I ask because in some cases, I have the same type of component used dozens of places in my HTML. So I'm just repeating bind definitions all over the place. Seems like I should just be able to use `<todo-item></todo-item>` in my HTML and be done with it.

I've tried to add the binding in the component template but that didn't seem to be working unless my syntax was off. I can't seem to see any way to do this in the documentation.

Is it possible? If not, why? Seems like it's encouraging the opposite of DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your idea, do you mean that since all the `todo-item` use same props, you prefer to use `<todo-item></todo-item>` rather than `<todo-item v-bind:item="..." ...></todo-item>`?

Comment: I think so yes. I am new to Vue though also so perhaps I am misunderstanding why you would or wouldn't want to do that? My thought process is that is, if a component is the same everywhere I use it, why am I defining the same bindings over and over and over again?

Comment: If all the props are totally same in every component, you don't even need to use `props`, just use `data` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data` proprerty in the definition of the component.

The example uses the new 'allprop' proprerty to get the full object, then in the data function it constructs the objects as needed:

```
<div id="app">

    <todo-item v-bind:allprop="todo"></todo-item>

</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('todo-item', {
        props: ['allprop'],
        template: '<div>{{ allprop.text }}</div>',
        data: function() {
            return {
                key: this.allprop.id,
                class: [this.allprop.someValue],
                ... more ...
            };
        }
    });
</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjpqz387/132/

Comment: Hmmm okay. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the purpose of props. In your example, where do I define a value for `this.allprop.someValue` ? On the data object?